# How to show the constant for the property instead of value

Tags: .net, visual-studio, colors, designer, systemcolors

Hello
I am working in VB.Net 2010 framework 2.0.
Suppose I declare a property :

```
Dim NewColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(150, 145, 145)

Private _myColor As Color = NewColor 
Public Property MyColor() As Color
    Get
        Return _myColor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        _myColor = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In the form designer, the property "MyColor" will be seen the value as 150, 145, 145. I want to see this value as "NewColor" in form designer.
This is the same like ControlDark, ActiveBorder etc. system colors. I want that instead of the color value, designer should show the variable name.
The .Net framework also use the above implementation for System Colors and same i want to do.

Thanks for any reply in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but not easy.

You should define your own type, probably hide the current property in the browser, with a `<Browsable(False)>` attribute, and create a shadow property that is of your own type. This type should know when it is "pointing to" a variable, or has a color itself.

On the new type you should override ToString, to return what you want to display. And create your own Editor. Look at [EditorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx) for more information.

You can create a dropdown, like Color has, with an extra tab that lists your variables.

If you do not want to create the extra properties (it is bad OO), you can also define a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter_methods.aspx) on the class, and specify each property and how to behave yourself.

BTW: The Color structure stores a KnownColor value (Color.Red or SystemColor.WindowText) or the RGB values. This way it knows that it points to a known color. Your structure should also know if it points to a variable (and what variable) or is a System.Color.

Comment: Can you please provide any sample?

Comment: Don't think about short 10 line fixes for this. On MSDN there are examples. For Editor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53c49eck.aspx, for TypeConverter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution you are saying is the answer. Thanks again